# datepicker onselect is not working [when datepicker div created dynamically]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a `datepicker` function which seems to be working but its `onSelect` function is not working i cannot see the `alert()`

```
$(function() {
var divContent = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter date" class="dupInput" id="gl_img_datepicker" readonly=""><button id="gl_img_datepicker_init">Date</button>';


jQuery('body').on('click', '#gl_img_datepicker_init', function(e) {
        jQuery("#gl_img_datepicker").datepicker('show');
 });

//onselect datepicker function 
jQuery('#gl_img_datepicker').datepicker('option', 'onSelect',
   function(dateText, inst) {
     alert('glImgExpiry-->' + dateText);
});
jQuery('body').on('click', '#mybutton', function(e) {
  jQuery("#my_div").append(divContent)
  jQuery("#gl_img_datepicker").datepicker();        
});

});
```

### Check my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/vdLwvmxp/32/)

---

I have already seen below questions but it did not help.

[Datepicker onSelect Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754196/datepicker-onselect-not-firing)

[jquery datepicker onselect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928147/jquery-datepicker-onselect-not-working)

[Datepicker onSelect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931557/datepicker-onselect-not-working)

[jQuery Datepicker onSelect is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249012/jquery-datepicker-onselect-is-not-working)

Thanks

Comment: nope not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign that event to the field that doesn't exist yet (meaning before the #gl_img_datepicker is being created and inserted into the document). Try it like this (here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qo0796kh/)):

```
$(function() {
    var divContent = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter date" class="dupInput" id="gl_img_datepicker" readonly=""><button id="gl_img_datepicker_init">Date</button>';


    jQuery('body').on('click', '#gl_img_datepicker_init', function(e) {
            jQuery("#gl_img_datepicker").datepicker('show');
     });

    jQuery('body').on('click', '#mybutton', function(e) {
        jQuery("#my_div").append(divContent)
        jQuery("#gl_img_datepicker").datepicker();    

        // We have already appended the divContent to the document; we
        // can continue with the actual datepicker event for that field

        //onselect datepicker function 
        jQuery('#gl_img_datepicker').datepicker('option', 'onSelect',
           function(dateText, inst) {
             alert('glImgExpiry-->' + dateText);
        });    
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans @user1680977 ----is there a better way to do this ?? .. in same context I have told ?

Comment: Thanks for the genius answer , I hope this is right way to do it. Anyways all that matters for me is, it works :) ..thank you so much

Comment: Yeah, I'd do it like this, however, if you want to have multiple of this inputn fields, you should go with `.classes` instead of `#ids`